# tex4ebook: unable to include picture using \includegraphics and package \usepackage

Tags: miktex2.9, tex4ebook

**The preamble of the tex file:**

%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.  

\special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}  
\begin{document}

**The latex code block dealing with including graphics:**

\begin{figure}  
\centering  
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Integration.png}  
%\par\end{centering}    
\end{figure}    

**The tex4ebook command when executed goes like this:**

tex4ebook -s test2.tex -f epub3 mathml  
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: test2.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode

**dvipng: Fatal error, PK file C:\Users\srirams05\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/cx/jknappen/ec/dpi576\ecrm1000.pk ends prematurely**

        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the file specified.
        1 file(s) copied.
HTML Tidy for Windows released on 25 March 2009
        1 file(s) copied.
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

The only issue with the `EPUB` outout is that the figure is missing. If the `LaTeX` code block above dealing with the figure is removed there is no issue... I suspect that the issue is with `dvipng` and `MikTeX`...

I am using the `tex4ebook` provided with **MikTex 2.9**.

Comment: do you have fully updated Miktex? There was an issue with the Graphics package recently, but it should be fixed for some time.

Comment: the error message you show is unrelated to graphics inclusion you have corrupted fonts `dpi576\ecrm1000.pk ends prematurely` but also your miktex is misconfigured it should not be using pk (bitmap) fonts for T1 encoded computer modern, it should be using scalable fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there should be no `dvipng` command involved if everything worked correctly. only file name of the png file should be included in the HTML code, no conversion should be started.

Comment: @michal.h21 I downloaded MikTex a few weeks back and I updated today on the MikTex console.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would welcome any thoughts on how to fix possible corrupted fonts or miktex misconfiguration.

Comment: @MathDilettante sorry I have never used miktex, so I can tell you the  behaviour is wrong but I don't know miktex's configuration system.

Comment: If i compile using pdftex either from within LyX or MikTex, no issues with the output. The graphics is properly rendered.

Comment: @MathDilettante it is then probably caused by older version of `.4ht` files in Miktex

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the PNG file is wrongly recoginzed and TeX4ht tries to include it as an EPS file. This causes the invocation of `dvipng`. Try to place this file, `graphics.4ht` to the directory with your document:

```
% graphics.4ht (2019-11-25-09:03), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.

   \expandafter\let\csname includegraphics \endcsname\includegraphics
\def\includegraphics{\expandafter\protect\csname includegraphics \endcsname}
\def\grf:removequote"#1"{#1}
\def\grf:thrashname#1\relax{}
\def\grf:fixquotes{%
    \@ifnextchar"{\edef\Gin@base{\expandafter\grf:removequote\Gin@base}\grf:thrashname}{\grf:thrashname}}
\def\grp:warning#1{\no:bound#1(no BoundingBox)//\:warning{#1}}
\def\no:bound#1(no BoundingBox)#2//{\gdef\noBoundingBox{#2}\ifx
   \noBoundingBox\empty \global\let\noBoundingBox\:UnDef\fi}
\let\:tempc\Gin@setfile
\pend:defIII\:tempc{\a:graphics
    \global\let\noBoundingBox\:UnDef
    \let\@latex@error\grp:warning \let\@ehc\empty}
\append:defIII\:tempc{\b:graphics\grf:gobble\leavevmode grf:gobble}
\HLet\Gin@setfile\:tempc
\NewConfigure{graphics*}[2]{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname :.#1\endcsname\relax
      \pend:defIII\n:Gin@setfile:{\csname :.#1\endcsname}%
   \fi
   \def\:temp{#2}\ifx \:temp\empty
     \expandafter\let\csname :.#1\endcsname\:UnDef
   \else
     \expandafter\def\csname :.#1\endcsname{\edef\:temp{\detokenize{.#1}}%
        \ifx \:temp\Gin@ext  \let\a:graphics\relax
           \def\G:cnfg{#2}\expandafter\grf:gobble \fi}%
   \fi }
\NewConfigure{graphics}{2}
\def\grf:gobble#1\leavevmode#2grf:gobble{%
   \PictureOff\expandafter\grf:fixquotes\Gin@base\relax#1\PictureOn \G:cnfg \let\G:cnfg\relax}
\let\G:cnfg\relax

\let\old:GreadEps\Gread@eps
\def\Gread@eps#1{\old:GreadEps{"#1"}}
\def\if:boundingbox#1#2{\ifdim\Gin@req@width=\Gin@nat@width\ifx\noBoundingBox\UnDefined#1\else#2\fi\else#1\fi}

\Hinput{graphics}
\endinput
```

It is the current code responsible for the graphics inclusion.

Comment: This worked. I noticed that MikTex has two versions of tex4ht (one of them it says is MikTex specific). And one version of make4ht and tex4ebook. I wonder if tex4ebook calls an incorrect version of tex4ht. In any case, I have a solution.

Comment: @MathDilettante I think there are separate packages with binaries and TeX files for TeX4ht in Miktex. I think the TeX files are just not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced missing images also, but the source of the problem was entirely different. It seems that tex4ebook (v0.3g, ubuntu) was almost but not quite handling relative directories for images. The images were in `../maps` relative to the .tex file and the tex4ebook command left behind a directory that appears to be the output it used to create the final zipped `.epub` file. In that directory it already had a `maps` directory in the correct location, but it had not been included in the  final file. Thus, the following command added the folder to the epub and fixed the final file:

```
zip -ur mybook.epub maps
```

After that images looked fine in the Amazon previewer.